Prevent line breaks after certain number of lines in a text area or contenteditable div
I want to create a text area or contenteditable div (preferably a text area) that has a max number of lines where, when hitting the max line, no new line breaks are added and all new text is hidden (but still exists).
I have tried using both text areas and contenteditable div's and I have been able to get them to stop resizing after max lines but new content that is added still causes line breaks and pushes existing text out of view.
For a crude demo:
current (max lines is 3):
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa (text gets hidden because of max lines)
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa (overflows to a new line)

wanted
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa (text is still visible)
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa (continues on the same line, getting hidden but still exising)

Here is a fiddle with what I have so far: fiddle

Start with a bit of debugging - e.g.console.log lineHeight.

If you are actively typing, the cursor will always be in view, which will result in old overflowing lines to go out of view. I don't think there is a way to achieve what is mentioned in this question. Or do you want the above behaviour after input blur event of the textbox?

While you could use clip-path to hide subseqent text, is this really what you want to do - i.e. the user typing but not able to see what they have typed and with no ability to edit it?

After a bit more research, it seems like this is not possible and it is probably better to use a custom element.
I ended up using the maxlength attribute of a text area because I realized that I was already preventing the user from using Enter to create a new line so the number of characters in the text area was accurate enough to use.

Are you using a monospace font? That would be useful info to add to the question. As would the prevention of new line input.
